# A question on completely continuous operators

Tags: banach-spaces

An operator $T:X\rightarrow Y$ is said to be completely continuous if $T$ maps weakly convergent sequences to norm convergent sequences.

Let $Q: l_{1}\rightarrow l_{2}$ be any surjection and $J:l_{1}\rightarrow Y$ be an isomorphic embedding.

Question. Is there a completely continuous operator $S:Y\rightarrow l_{2}$ such that $Q=SJ$?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe clarify: Are $X, Y$ Banach spaces? Are $T,Q,J$ linear bounded operators?

Comment: @PietroMajer Yes. $X,Y$ are Banach spaces and all operators mean linear bounded operators.

Comment: Giving an explicit example of $Q$ (bounded linear surjection $\ell_1\to \ell_2$) would help, I think.

Comment: @JeanDuchon, this is standard. The map that sends the unit vector basis of $\ell_1$ to the unit vector basis of $\ell_2$ extends to a bounded linear operator, simply because the $\ell_1$ norm is a certain sense maximal.

Comment: @TomekKania  Isn't $\ell_1$ the space of summable sequences (and $\ell_2$ that of square summable ones)? The inclusion  $\ell_1\subset\ell_2$ is not onto, so what did I miss? Is it obvious that a bounded linear _surjection_ exists? I can't see any example...

Comment: @JeanDuchon, sorry, sille my. I meant any map that sends the uvb of $\ell_1$ onto arbitrary countable, dense subset of the sphere of $\ell_2$.

Comment: @TomekKania So, any denumerable dense subset $S$ of the unit sphere of a separable Hilbert space $\cal H$ has the property that each $x\in\cal H$ is expressible as $x=\sum_{s\in S}c_s s$ with $\sum|c_s|<\infty$, right? Whose theorem is this? And is it true for (some other) Banach spaces?

Comment: @JeanDuchon true for all Banach spaces. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1538920/every-separable-banach-space-is-isomorphic-to-ell-1-a-for-some-closed-a-subs/1540061#1540061

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Grothendieck's theorem, $Q$ is absolutely summing, in particular $2$-summing. As such, it has a $2$-summing extension to $Y$, by Pietsch's factorisation theorem. But $2$-summing operators are completely continuous (again by Pietsch's theorem).